# Could not simulate the action button click on react-enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm running the **mocha**+**enzyme** test for a ReactJs application. On debugging, I get the following:

```
<div id="login" className="card">
<div>
<h1>
  Welcome
</h1>
<p>
  Login to manage your business.
</p>
<div className="tabs">
  <i onClick={[Function]} data-tab="0" className="fa fa-phone active" aria-hidden="true" />
  <i onClick={[Function]} data-tab="1" className="fa fa-at" aria-hidden="true" />
</div>
<div className="inputs">
  <PhoneNumber countryData={{...}} 
    suggestions={{...}} 
    onChange={[Function]} 
    onSubmit={[Function]} 
    autofocus={true} 
    value="123456789"
    selectedCountry="India" 
    validationHandler={[Function]} />
</div>
<button className="button" type="button" onClick={[Function]}>
  Continue
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

And whenever I have tried to simulate the click action, it returns false.

I'm attaching my test script here:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Login onSubmit={onButtonClick} />);
wrapper.setState({ tab: 0 }); 
wrapper.setState({ clientNumber: '123456798' });
wrapper.setState({clientCountry: "India"});
wrapper.setProps({ countryData: {"name": "India","dial_code": "+91","code": "IN"}});
wrapper.setProps({suggestions: ["Iraq", "Ireland"]});

console.log(wrapper.debug()); 
expect(wrapper.find('button')).to.have.length(1); #passing and return true

const onButtonClick = sinon.spy();
wrapper.find('button').last().simulate('click');
expect(onButtonClick.calledOnce).to.equal(true); #return false
```

I'm new to enzyme and reactjs, so don't know whether I'm doing it correctly. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Your sinon spy is not attached to the button in any way. You created the spy, but when you simulate the click, it calls the function defined in the markup (not your `const onButtonClick`).

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan27 : So,Can you please tell me what should I do here to fix this ?